# Get index of Pandas Dataframe where some columns are zero

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is probably very simple but I can't seem to make it work for some reason. Let's say I have a dataframe:

```
    A   B   C   D   E  ... Z
1   0   2   3   0   5  ... 0
2   5   0   0   0   4  ... 1
3   0   0   3   0   10 ... 12
4   4   0   0   0   0  ... 0
```

and a list `col` that has certain columns of the dataframe

How can I return a list of the index of the rows for which columns of `col` are all 0? For example if `col = ['B', 'C', 'D']` I would like it to return `idx = [2, 4]`

I tried doing `idx = df.index[df.loc[col].sum() == 0].tolist()` but I get a `ValueError` even though all the columns exist in the dataframe.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `all`. `sum` is not a good option as it's probably more expensive to compute the sum and you would potentially have false positives if there are negative values:

```
col = ['B', 'C', 'D']

df.index[df[col].eq(0).all(axis=1)].to_list()
```

output: `[2, 4]`

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks! Any ideas why my code was throwing an error?

Comment: You used `loc` incorrectly and were summing on the wrong axis. You needed `df[col].sum(axis=1)` or `df.loc[:,col].sum(axis=1)`